# Inserting date to datetime field

Tags: datetime, vbscript, sql-server-2012

I am using vbscript to update datetime field of sql server 2012 database. Code is as follows:

```
Dim cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
cmd.ActiveConnection = connection   
'Prepare the stored procedure
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[spMyProc]"
cmd.CommandType = 4  'adCmdStoredProc     

cmd.Parameters("@complete_date") = Now()

cmd.Execute
```

But the field in database shows only date part not the time part: for time it shows 00:00:00. I am not able to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like? Also, did you try creating the parameter with type `adDBTimeStamp`? (`cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@complete_date", 135, 1, , Now)`)

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, In my stored procedure I have declared date variable as "date" instead of "datetime". I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my stored procedure I have declared date variable as "date" instead of "datetime"